# How to set 2 flex items on row and the last item in a row expand full width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a css flex way to set 2 items per row and in each row the second item to expand with width auto.

I tried a lot of things, like setting margin-right:auto for second item in each row, but is not working.

Here is what I have now:

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
div span{
  background:red;
  margin:2px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div span:nth-child(2),
div span:nth-child(4),
div span:nth-child(6){
  flex-basis:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>aaa</span>
  <span>bbbbbb</span>
  <span>ccccccccc</span>
  <span>ddd</span>
  <span>eee</span>
  <span>fff</span>
</div>
```

The text inside a flex item should not wrap.

Here is the result I need:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the red box to be the same and yellow to cover the rest width?

Comment: @Ankit Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This layout can't work with Flex, because each row is independent from other rows, and column widths cannot be defined.

However, the solution is simple with Grid, because column widths can be defined.

```css
 div {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
 }

 div span {
   background: red;
 }

 div span:nth-child(2),
 div span:nth-child(4),
 div span:nth-child(6) {
   background: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>aaa</span>
  <span>bbbbbb </span>
  <span>ccccccccc</span>
  <span>ddd</span>
  <span>eee</span>
  <span>fff</span>
</div>
```

In the code above, `grid-template-columns` defines two columns.

The first is set to width `min-content`, which means it will size to the minimum width possible.

The second is set to `1fr`, which means it will take all remaining space.

Comment: One single note: 'white-space:nowrap;' needet on span to prevent text going on new line when using multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated with no wrap for text**

Here is a quick example, which hopefully achieves the desired result.

It works on the posted HTML structure, just made some changes on CSS in `<style>`.

Example: (see it in live with the button below)

```html
<style>
div {
  /*  edit left span width here */
  --left-span-width: 150px;
  /*  edit gap of span here */
  --span-gap: 2px;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--span-gap);
}

div span:nth-child(odd) {
  width: calc(var(--left-span-width) - var(--span-gap));
  background: red;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div span:nth-child(even) {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% - var(--left-span-width));
  background: yellow;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<div>
  <span>aaa</span>
  <span>bbbbbb</span>
  <span>ccccccccc ccccccccc ccccccccc</span>
  <span>ddd</span>
  <span>eee</span>
  <span>fff</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working. If you replace `ccccccccc` with `ccccccccc ccccccccc` the text will break. Second, I don't really understand what represents that "15%".

Comment: @Andrei I see, I did not realize the text also need to have no wrap. I have updated the code with this, and also removed the 15%. Instead I added some comment on setting a custom `width` for the left `span`. Hope it might get closer to the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the time spent. Unfortunately, the '150px' size makes me problems. I don't want to set a size for a column. I want, somehow, to let them adjust their self...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item  {
  width: 100%
}

.container  {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > span {
  flex: 50%; /* or - flex: 0 50% - or - flex-basis: 50% - */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}   
span:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}

span:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">aaa</span>
  <span class="item">bbbbbb</span>
  <span class="item">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
  <span class="item">ddd</span>
  <span class="item">eee</span>
  <span class="item">fff</span>

</div>
```

Comment: The result is totaly different from what I want.